# Buffer with no overlap

Tags: python, buffer, geopandas

I have a GeoDataFrame of a (tiny) street network and want to [buffer](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) with no overlap.
Thus far I have:

```py
#- get the stuff
rd = gpd.read_file('./data/roads-cput_proj.geojson')
rd.set_crs(epsg=32734, inplace=True, allow_override=True)
rd['lanes'] = rd['tags'].apply(lambda x: x.get('lanes'))
rd['lanes'] = pd.to_numeric(rd['lanes'])
#- clean
rd = rd[rd['geometry'].type != 'Polygon']
rd = rd[rd.geometry.length > 10]
rd.dropna(subset=['lanes'], inplace=True)
rd_buffer = rd.copy()

#- buffer_func
def buffer(row):
    #return row.geometry.buffer(row.lanes * 1.5)
    return row.geometry.buffer(round(float(row['lanes']) * 1.5, 2), 
                               cap_style=2, join_style=2)

#-- loop through and trim each geometry based on how it overlaps
for i, row in rd_buffer.iterrows():
    #-- the entire street network without this one segment at i
    rd_copy = rd.copy()
    #-- delete one street
    rd_copy.drop(i, axis=0, inplace=True)
    rd_copy['geometry'] = rd_copy.apply(buffer, axis=1)
    #-- union
    union = rd_copy.explode().dissolve()

    #-- now the single steet at i that needs to be trimmed
    g = row.geometry.buffer(round(float(row['lanes']) * 1.8, 2), 
                               cap_style=2)
    g = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=jparams['crs'], geometry=[g])
    #-- difference: g minus union
    g = gpd.overlay(g, union, how='difference')
    #- I want the result to be a polygon so overwrite the geometry at that index
    rd_buffer.at[i, 'geometry'] = g.geometry[0]
    #break
```

If I uncomment the `break` I get (zoomed):

[image]

---where the buffered green polygon represents one street segment trimed back from the its perpendicular connection; *it would overlap with when that road is buffered.*

Without the `break`; I get:

[image]

Overlaps remain (nothing is *trimmed*).
Where has the loop gone wrong?
the data is [here](https://github.com/AdrianKriger/osm_LoD1_3DCityModel/blob/main/village_campus/extra/roads-cput_proj.geojson) ~ 79KB.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want and how the result is wrong. What exactly is your code supposed to do? How would a correct result look like (maybe draw in the image in blue)?

Comment: Have you looked into the GeoPandas [`dissolve`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/aggregation_with_dissolve.html) method?

Comment: @bugmenot123.  I want to buffer the line features without intersections while maintaining their attributes. With the code I have; when line features connect start-end there are no intersections. Where line features DO NOT connect start-end (like along an edge) they intersect. I want a buffer that connects but not overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the direction of [ET Spatial Techniques](https://www.ian-ko.com/ET_SolutionCenter12/ETSC_NonOverlappingBuffers_Polylines.html); which recommened Voronoi. With python:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

import shapely
from shapely.wkt import loads
import itertools
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d, Delaunay

def segmentize(geom):
        wkt = geom.wkt  # shapely Polygon to wkt
        geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)  # create ogr geometry
        geom.Segmentize(5)  # densify geometry
        wkt2 = geom.ExportToWkt()  # ogr geometry to wkt
        new = loads(wkt2)  # wkt to shapely Polygon
        return new
    
def buffer(row):
    return row.geometry.buffer(round(float(row['lanes']) * 1.2, 2), cap_style=1)

#-- read a basic cleaning
rd = gpd.read_file('./data/roads-cput_proj.geojson')
rd.set_crs(epsg=32734, inplace=True, allow_override=True)
rd['lanes'] = rd['tags'].apply(lambda x: x.get('lanes'))
rd['lanes'] = pd.to_numeric(rd['lanes'])
rd['bridge'] = rd['tags'].apply(lambda x: x.get('bridge'))
rd['name'] = rd['tags'].apply(lambda x: x.get('name'))
rd.name = rd.name.fillna(np.nan)
rd['highway'] = rd['tags'].apply(lambda x: x.get('highway'))
rd = rd[rd['geometry'].type != 'Polygon']#) & (rd['lanes'] != np.nan)]
rd.dropna(subset=['lanes'], inplace=True)

#-- i want a vertex every 5-metre
rd['geometry'] = rd['geometry'].apply(segmentize)

#-- need to find where the segments intersect
inters = []
for line1, line2 in itertools.combinations(rd.geometry, 2):
    if line1.intersects(line2):
         inter = line1.intersection(line2)
         if "Point" == inter.type:
             inters.append(inter)
         elif "MultiPoint" == inter.type:
             inters.extend([pt for pt in inter])
         elif "MultiLineString" == inter.type:
              multiLine = [line for line in inter]
              first_coords = multiLine[0].coords[0]
              last_coords = multiLine[len(multiLine)-1].coords[1]
              inters.append(Point(first_coords[0], first_coords[1]))
              inters.append(Point(last_coords[0], last_coords[1]))
          elif "GeometryCollection" == inter.type:
              for geom in inter:
                  if "Point" == geom.type:
                      inters.append(geom)
                  elif "MultiPoint" == geom.type:
                      inters.extend([pt for pt in geom])
                  elif "MultiLineString" == geom.type:
                      multiLine = [line for line in geom]
                      first_coords = multiLine[0].coords[0]
                      last_coords = multiLine[len(multiLine)-1].coords[1]
                      inters.append(Point(first_coords[0], first_coords[1]))
                      inters.append(Point(last_coords[0], last_coords[1]))

#-- buffer the intersection vertices           
pnts = gpd.GeoDataFrame(crs='epsg:32734', geometry=inters)
p_buffer = pnts.buffer(2)
p_buffer = gpd.GeoDataFrame(crs='epsg:32734', geometry=p_buffer)

#-- remove the intersection from the streets    
rd_e = gpd.overlay(rd, p_buffer, how='difference')
rd_e = rd_e.explode()
rd_e.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

#-- stack all vertices (i included the area-of-interest; the boundary)
pt = [line.__geo_interface__['coordinates'] for line in rd_e.geometry]
pt_array = np.array(np.concatenate(pt))
po = [i for i in aoibuffer.geometry]
x,y = po[0].exterior.coords.xy
po = np.dstack((x,y))
po_array = np.array(np.concatenate(po))
pt_array = np.concatenate((pt_array, po_array), axis=0)
#-- scipy voronoi
vor = Voronoi(pt_array)
lines = [shapely.geometry.LineString(vor.vertices[line]) for line in vor.ridge_vertices if -1 not in line]
polys = shapely.ops.polygonize(lines)
vo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.GeoSeries(polys), crs='epsg:32734')
#-- spatial join to transfer the street attributes 
join = gpd.sjoin(vo, rd_e, how="left", op="intersects")

#-- buffer and union the entire dataset and clip previous 
rd_b = rd.copy()
rd_b['geometry'] = rd_b.apply(buffer, axis=1)
rd_b = gpd.geoseries.GeoSeries([geom for geom in rd_b.unary_union.geoms])
rd_b.set_crs(crs='epsg:32734', inplace=True, allow_override=True)
rd_b = rd_b.explode()
rd_b = gpd.clip(rd_b, aoi)
one = gpd.clip(join, rd_b)
one.set_crs(crs='epsg=32734', inplace=True, allow_override=True)
#-- merge features where name and rd:type (highway) match
one = one.dissolve(by=['name', 'highway'], as_index=False, dropna=False)
one = one.explode()
one.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [unary_union](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.unary_union.html) ([Shapely unary_union](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union))

Buffer with intersections

[image]

```
union = rd_buffer.unary_union
```

Four polygons without intersection

[image]

But you lose the original attributes.

Comment: mmmm... the individual line features buffered, seperate, connected but not overlapping with their attributes would be pretty awesome.